# Git Ignore folders in specific paths

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a rule on gitignore file to exclude folders with name "bar" but I want to "un-ignore" if the "bar" folder is below "foo"

- ignore:
  *bar/*
- but allow:
  *foo/bar*

Is it possible? How can I do it?

I tryed:

```
bar/
!foo/bar/
```

and

```
bar/
foo/*
!foo/bar/
```

and many other options but no luck.

what happens is that it ignores (prevent commit) both "bar" folders or none, I can't make it ignore only the one that is outside "foo"

Comment: The phrase "no luck" is meaningless. What actually happened that you think is "wrong" in some way?

Comment: "it ignores both "bar" folders or none" But how do you know? You have not answered my simple question: what happened? Don't tell us your conclusions, show us actual evidence of an issue. You might have incorrect expectations about what the gitignore file does. How do we know?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are asking. what I'm trying to say is if I add "bar/" to the git ignore file, it ignores both "bar" folders, the one in the root and the one in the "foo" folder. and when I add "!foo/bar/" to try to un-ignore it, it still ignores both "bar" folders. what i was expecting is that with "!foo/bar/" it would un-ignore that folder and just ignore the "bar" folder in the root.

Comment: by "it ignores" i mean git dont commit that file. Im watching on visual studio, and the files appear with a "forbiden sign" telling that that file wont be commited. when i remove all the rules on gitignore, the files appear with a "+" sign telling that the files will be commited. what i want is that the files in "foo" folder are all commited, and the ones in the "bar" folder in the root dont.
thanks for your help but i think i cant explain it better

Comment: So this is actually about Visual Studio, not Git. You need to edit your question accordingly.

Comment: so, what im doing in the gitignore file is correct, only visual studio is understanding it wrongly?

Comment: @TeKapa I'd recommend using the git command line  (git add, git commit, git status) to determine if it is a VS Code issue or a git issue. If the issue occurs in the git cli, it's a git issue, if it only occurs in VSCode, it's a VSCode issue.

Comment: You're drawing conclusions again. Stop it. I didn't say that. I know nothing about Visual Studio and I don't care about it. I'm just trying to help you ask a good question. Describe facts, not conclusions. So far, your question has no facts.

Comment: Im trying to understand your conclusion that this is a visual studio issue and not git.

Comment: I have drawn no conclusion at all — because you have provided no facts. Take some time to consider the concept of a [mcve]. Then revise your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible? How can I do it?

The first solution you mentioned works.

Output of `git status --untracked-files=all .` without the `.gitignore` file:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        bar/something.txt
        foo/bar/something.txt
```

So we see two files are new and reported as "untracked".

If we now create a `.gitignore` file with the following content

```
bar/
!foo/bar/
```

the output changes to

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
        foo/bar/something.txt
```

so *git*

- picks up our newly created `.gitignore` file
- ignores the `bar/something.txt` which is still present on the filesystem
- but does not ignore the `foo/bar/something.txt`